# How to use jquery to remove a li item from ul and add to another on the same page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove a li item from one ul to another within the same page using JQuery, I've tried two ways but have been unsuccessful so far. In my last attempt I tried to use the delegate method and wire a click event on the button with class .checked. However, this deletes everything from the current ul I'm trying to remove the item from and doesn't add it to the the second ul with id completed tasks.

Here are the two ul I'm trying to manipulate:

```
    <ul id="incomplete-tasks">
     <li><label>Milk</label><button class="check">Check</button></li>
     <li><label>Bread</label><button class="check">Check</button></li>
     <li><label>Eggs</label><button class="check">Check</button></li>
   </ul>  

    <ul id="completed-tasks">
    <li><label>Fruits</label><button class="uncheck">Uncheck</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li><label>Shoes</label><button class="uncheck">Uncheck</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li><label>Fruits</label><button class="uncheck">Uncheck</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
  </ul>
```

And here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $add_button = $('#add-item')
    var newItem;
    var $incompleteTasks = $('#incomplete-tasks');
    var $completedTasks = $('#completed-tasks')

    var li = $('<li></li>');
    var label = $('<label></label>');
    var button = $('<button class="check">Check</button>')


    $(document.body).on("click", 'button.check', function () {
        var $checked = $(this).parent();
        // var $ticked = $(this).prev()//get value of label element

        // label.text($ticked);
        // li.append(label); 
        // li.append(button);
        // $completedTasks.append(li); 

        $incompleteTasks.delegate("button.checked", "click", removeAndAdd);

        $checked.parent().remove();
    });

    $add_button.click(function () {

        newItem = $('#new-task').val();

        //create li element and assign it to variable


        //Use input value as the text for li item
        label.text(newItem);


        //append new item to incomplete tasks ul

        $incompleteTasks.append(li);
        li.append(label);
        li.append(button);

    });

});

function removeAndAdd() {
    var $incompleteTasks = $('#incomplete-tasks');
    var $completedTasks = $('#completed-tasks')

    $completedTasks.append(this);

}
```

Comment: So clicking the check button should move it to the second list, clicking the uncheck button should move it to the first list, while clicking the delete button removes an element altogether? Side question, why have a label element if you're not associating it with another element.

Comment: @j08691 yes that's right. About the label - I've got some styling associated with it in CSS and removing requries re-adjusting some elements which needs a bit of time and will get to that once I have the functionality working in JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried using .remove() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
$('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', 'button.check', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('check').addClass('uncheck').text('Uncheck').after('<button class="delete">Delete</button>').addBack().parent('li').appendTo('#completed-tasks');
})
$('#completed-tasks').on('click', 'button.uncheck', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('uncheck').addClass('check').text('Check').next().remove().addBack().parent('li').appendTo('#incomplete-tasks');
})
$('#completed-tasks').on('click', 'button.delete', function () {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/85ea6mLc/)**

The above uses `.on()`'s event delegation syntax to handle the movement of elements.

Answer (score 1):

When you append, you just remove it from the current parent and put it in another.  You can just walk up the tree to find the parent, and move it to the appropriate container:

```
$(document.body).on("click", 'button.check', function(){
   $(this)
      .removeClass('check')
      .addClass('uncheck')
      .parentsUntil('li').parent().appendTo('#completed-tasks');
      // add other handling.
});
$(document.body).on("click", 'button.uncheck', function(){
   $(this)
      .removeClass('uncheck')
      .addClass('check')
      .parentsUntil('li').parent().appendTo('#incomplete-tasks');
      // add other handling.
});
```

Also, for the delete button, you can just have it there always in your model, and hide it via css:

```
#incomplete-tasks .delete { display:none  }
```

Comment: I think this works too, but the answer from j08691 is close to what I was trying to do. Appreciate the help.